# PHP dynamic for loop validation

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to validate this form dynamically using PHP so each file gets the same validation instead of only one file being validated. Below is my code to try and explain this better.

This is the for loop which outputs a number of `<input type="file" />` fields to the user.

```
$items = sanitize($_GET['item']);

for($i=1; $i<=$items; $i++) {
    echo $item = '<input type="file" name="photo'. $i .'" />';
}
```

This is the validation for one of these fields

```
$file_size = $_FILES['photo1']['size'];    
if($file_size > 10485760) {
          echo 'Photo 1 is too large. Maximium file size is 10MB.';
}
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this validation for every field in the `for` loop. This is what I have tried so far.

```
if($file_size.$i > 10485760) {
echo 'Photo '. $i .' is too large. Please choose a smaller file.';
}
```

This does not work though. Please can someone help me out with this?

Many thanks in advance, Harry

Comment: numbered variables are a bad habit - use arrays instead: name="photo[$i]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array keys can be dynamic:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $some_limit; $i++) {
   $size = $_FILES["photo{$i}"]['size'];
   if ($size > ...) { etc... }
}
```

With your `$size . $i`, you'd be taking the size of the first file, e.g. `1024` bytes, and concatenating it with the $i value, e.g. `1024 . 2` and ending up with `10242`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
foreach ($_FILES as $id => $details) {
  $size = $details['size'];
  # validate...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

input name can be with square bracket. When form is submitted input fields can be accessed as array. such as:

html form:

```
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
<input type="file" name="photo[]">
```

php:

```
foreach($_FILES['photo'] as $key => $p) {
$file_size = $p['size'];    
if($file_size > 10485760) {
    echo "Photo $key is too large. Maximium file size is 10MB.";
}
}
```

This should work. Thank You.